# How to delete layout when button pressed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, arraylist, android-linearlayout

I am new to android please help me to find the appropriate solution for this situation.

please refer UI(image link) . I am trying to do if user clicks add button  new listview should inflate. and when user press the  delete button on particular  listview, entire row should get deleted.

**Problem 1** : when pressing delete wrong row is getting deleted.

**Problem 2** : when user press start group id value of all the added row should saved in arraylist.

**Problem 3** : I have to apply limit in add and delete .. User cannot add more than 20 row and at least one row should available i.e., user can't delete the all rows.

> UI looked like : [App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CRA2.jpg)

> code:XML file of each row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="time"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="delete" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> XML code of UI part

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/leanierLayout_test"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add"
                />
```

> OnCreate Method :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ap_auto_start_test);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,groupId);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Button add = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final LinearLayout data = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leanierLayout_test);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                    final View view = li.inflate(R.layout.tryandtest,null);
                    data.addView(view);
                    Spinner s = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    s.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    Button delete= findViewById(R.id.button2);
                    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            data.removeViewInLayout(view);
                        }
                    });

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("infilate exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a  recyclerView???

Comment: Is it simpler to implement this using recyclerView ?

Comment: does all the problems (problem: 1,2,3) earliy get resolved using recyclerView?

Comment: yes of course .

Comment: If you need more information, be sure to let me know.

Comment: Could you please help me to find solutions without using recyclerView.

Comment: @David Innocent has given you the answer.

Comment: https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-android-recyclerview-842e56adbfd8

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can look at doing CRUD functionality on a recyclerview. Stop using the listview. It is very inefficient.

The following link should give you a very clear guideline on how to achieve your functionality.

[Recycler view CRUD](http://programmingroot.com/android-recyclerview-crudinsertupdatedeleteview-list-tutorial-with-example/)